# angularjs: can't dynamically set filter method with scope data

Tags: angularjs, filter

In my angular application, I came into a filter related issue. I have reproduced this issue with a simple live demo as bellow:

https://jsfiddle.net/baoqger/fpo3j6gx/2/

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="filterCtrl as f">
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.inputdata"></input>
        <span ng-click="f.setFilter('lowercase')">First Filter</span>
        <span  ng-click="f.setFilter('uppercase')">Second Filter</span>
    <div ng-bind="f.inputdata | f.filtername"></div>
</div>
```

click `First Filter` or `Second Filter` will trigger the `setFilter` function.

```
function filterCtrl() {
    this.setFilter = function ( name ){
        this.filtername = name;
    }.bind(this);
}

angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('filterCtrl', filterCtrl)
```

In the controller, the `filtername` will be set to lowercase or upper case, depends on which button was clicked as mentioned above. 
Then set the `filtername` as filter method as below:

```
<div ng-bind="f.inputdata | f.filtername"></div>
```

But based on the error message, it seems that angular system can't support such usage. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/qs083b3w/):

**Javascript:**

```
.controller('filterCtrl', ['$filter' function($filter){
     var self = this;
     self.setFilter = function(name){
         self.filter = $filter(name);
     }
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="filterCtrl as f">
        <input type="text" ng-model="f.inputdata"></input>
        <span ng-click="f.setFilter('lowercase')">First Filter</span>
        <span  ng-click="f.setFilter('uppercase')">Second Filter</span>
    <div ng-bind="f.filter?f.filter(f.inputdata):f.inputdata"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for this case. If I need to filter list data, like `<div ng-repeat="item in itemlist | dynamicFilter">`. Can this solution still work?

Comment: At this case: `<div ng-repeat="item in f.filter(itemlist, additionalArgIfNeeded)">`